# Matplotlib plotting custom colormap with the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been following a tutorial on plotting F1 data over a circuit, color coded with the `fastf1` library.
I wanted to add some extra's to the script to utilize the official team colors.
It works but the end result shows the colormap with the circuit covering the `n bins 100`. [image: My plotting result]
In the picture above I used the same colormap as in the tutorial `'winter'` so there is most certainly something wrong in my code.

However, the original tutorial gets a cleaner end result with only the circuit showing like this: [image: Original result]

the tutorial in question uses a default colormap from matplotlib `'winter'`. To get the team colors working I had to create a custom colormap from the 2 colors that are fetched from api.

Let's get into the code, I have tried so much and searched everywhere without success...

The custom colormap is build with this sequence of code I got from the matplotlib docs.

```py
# Create custom colormap
teamcolor1 = to_rgb('{}'.format(team1_color))
teamcolor2 = to_rgb('{}'.format(team2_color))
colors = [teamcolor1, teamcolor2]
n_bins = [3, 6, 10, 100]
cmap_name = 'colors'
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 9))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.94, wspace=0.05)

x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10
for n_bin, ax in zip(n_bins, axs.ravel()):
    colormap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors, N=n_bin)
    im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=colormap)
    ax.set_title("N bins: %s" % n_bin)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    cm.register_cmap(cmap_name, colormap)
```

I register the colormap to easily call it later in the script with `get_cmap`.

The eventual plotting of the circuit is done in this piece of code:

```py
x = np.array(telemetry['X'].values)
y = np.array(telemetry['Y'].values)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
fastest_driver_array = telemetry['Fastest_driver_int'].to_numpy().astype(float)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('winter', 2)
lc_comp = LineCollection(segments, norm=plt.Normalize(1, cmap.N+1), cmap=cmap)
lc_comp.set_array(fastest_driver_array)
lc_comp.set_linewidth(5)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [18, 10]

plt.gca().add_collection(lc_comp)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tick_params(labelleft=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, bottom=False)

cbar = plt.colorbar(mappable=lc_comp, boundaries=np.arange(1, 4))
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(1.5, 9.5))
cbar.set_ticklabels(['{}'.format(driver1), '{}'.format(driver2)])

plt.savefig(
    '{}_'.format(year) + '{}_'.format(driver1) + '{}_'.format(driver2) + '{}_'.format(circuit) + '{}.png'.format(
        session), dpi=300)

plt.show()
```

This is where I think things go wrong, but I'm unsure of what is going wrong. I guess it has to do with how I use the colormap. But everything I changed broke the whole script.
As I don't have a lot of experience with matplotlib, it's getting very complicated.

As I don't want this question to be overly long the whole code can be read here:
https://gist.github.com/platinaCoder/7b5be22405f2003bd577189692a2b36b

Comment: Have you checked the tutorial on color maps in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colorbar-only-py)? You can use `mpl.colors.ListedColormap()` here to specify any color.

Comment: I have, the problem is that I'm getting 2 colors from an API which are the official color HEX codes from the F1 teams in question. Everything is going fine as the colors are plotted on the circuit, except that in exports in included with the colormap.

Comment: Hexadecimal code can be converted to rgba format and used for ListedColormap(). See This:[https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html#matplotlib.colors.to_rgba](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html#matplotlib.colors.to_rgba)

Comment: The colors are not the problem, I already convert the HEX to RGB Tuples here: `teamcolor1 = to_rgb('{}'.format(team1_color))`. The problem is the end result. I get a png where the whole colormap is visible, I just want the circuit with the side bar where the drivers are. I don't want to have those 3 cmaps into my final picture.

Comment: In the first part of the code, you create 4 colorbars (one for each subplot).  In the second part of the code you create a 5th colorbar from data from a line-collection.  As you don't specify an `ax`, it gets placed next to the last created subplot (lower right).  You could leave out creating the undesired color bars.  By the way, `mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#0000FF', '#00FF80'])` works without problem with hexadecimal colors, there is no need for conversions.

Comment: Man I'm stupid, it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a whole custome cmap, I got rid of this piece of code:

```py
# Create custom colormap
teamcolor1 = to_rgb('{}'.format(team1_color))
teamcolor2 = to_rgb('{}'.format(team2_color))
colors = [teamcolor1, teamcolor2]
n_bins = [3, 6, 10, 100]
cmap_name = 'colors'
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 9))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.94, wspace=0.05)

x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10
for n_bin, ax in zip(n_bins, axs.ravel()):
    colormap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors, N=n_bin)
    im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=colormap)
    ax.set_title("N bins: %s" % n_bin)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    cm.register_cmap(cmap_name, colormap)
```

and replaced `cmap = cm.get_cmap('colors', 2)` with `cmap = cm.colors.ListedColormap(['{}'.format(team1_color), '{}'.format(team2_color)])`